# keyframes animation not work in :before and :hover css

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components, keyframe

I have a problem with using keyframes in hover and before tags. I can't figure out why they don't work and how to make them work.
if i use them without keyframes, they work but in this case i have to use keyframes.
I'm using the "styled component" library

```
const tmp = keyframes`

     from, to {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 180%;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
            z-index: 1;
            transform: skew(45deg);
            transition: .5s;
     }
`;

const tmp1 = keyframes`

     from, to {
           left: -180%;
     }
`;

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      
      &:before {
            -webkit-animation: ${tmp} 1s forwards;         
      }
      
      &:hover:before {
           -webkit-animation: ${tmp1} 1s forwards;
      }
       
   `;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but I couldn’t see that syntax for keyframes in the documentation.

Try this instead

```
    const tmp = keyframes`

     from{}
     to {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 180%;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
            z-index: 1;
            transform: skew(45deg);
            transition: .5s;
     }
`;

const tmp1 = keyframes`

     from {}
    to {
           left: -180%;
     }
`;
```